# Give the gridview columns a alias name in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, gridview, alias

I have a GridView which is not DataSource bound. At run time this GridView shows some rows at run time. There is a requirement in which user should be able to change the column header text at run time. So i thought of to implement in this way -

User will double click [or single click] on column header and a text box will be visible to user, where user will enter the new text and as soon as user leaves the text box, new column header text will be set as HeaderText property of the column. Can this achieved? can anyone share the sample code to achieve the same? I will be highly obliged to you. Any help will be appreciable.

This is my grid

```
 <asp:GridView ID="GdvTestData" runat="server" 
        class="table table-striped table-responsive table-hover" 
        onrowdatabound="gv_RowDataBound" 
        PageSize="100" OnSelectedIndexChanged="GdvTestData_SelectedIndexChanged">
                <FooterStyle BorderStyle="Solid" />
</asp:GridView>
```

Comment: here you want to give alias to each column like select department as [dept], customerid as [id] from table. should be select department as [deptGrid1], customerid as [idFGrid1] from table.

Comment: I will not know the column names as table is selected by user at runtime. I am doing select * from table name. Now I need to allow users to give alias names to columns and display the table with alias name

Comment: and that alias you want to display at grid header name only right?

Comment: yes...GridView is not DataSource bound

Comment: There are many red flags with what you are doing here. First is allowing the end user to decide what table to view. This is a sign that something is not designed well. It also means you have to run everything as dynamic sql or your building up a string and executing it. This opens the door for sql injection. Then there is the select * which of course makes sense since you have a grid that can display anything.

Comment: If you don't know the fields when you do the select, how will you know the alias for those columns?

Comment: I have edited my question for better understanding

Comment: I have posted one asnwer you can try that

Answer (score 0):

Here is the thing that you can do to bind alias with the column
Below is aspx code

```
<asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="ddlQuery">
            <asp:ListItem Text="Query1" Value="1" Selected="True"></asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Text="Query2" Value="2"></asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Text="Query3" Value="3"></asp:ListItem>
        </asp:DropDownList>
        <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtAlias"></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnGetData" Text="GetData" OnClick="btnGetData_Click" />
        <asp:GridView runat="server" ID="gcData"></asp:GridView>
```

And code to bind data to grid in cs is below

```
protected void btnGetData_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            GetData();
        }

        private void GetData()
        {
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection();
            con.ConnectionString = "Connection String";

            string Query = string.Empty;
            if (ddlQuery.SelectedValue == "1")
                Query = "SELECT * FROM Table1";
            else if (ddlQuery.SelectedValue == "2")
                Query = "SELECT * FROM Table2";
            else if (ddlQuery.SelectedValue == "3")
                Query = "SELECT * FROM Table3";

            try
            {
                con.Open();
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
                cmd.Connection = con;
                cmd.CommandText = Query;
                SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                da.Fill(dt);

                DataTable dtFinal = new DataTable();
                foreach (DataColumn cln in dt.Columns)
                {
                    dtFinal.Columns.Add(cln.ColumnName + " " + txtAlias.Text, cln.DataType);
                }
                foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
                {
                    DataRow dr = dtFinal.NewRow();
                    for (int i = 0; i < dtFinal.Columns.Count; i++)
                    {                       
                        dr[i] = row[i];                        
                    }
                    dtFinal.Rows.Add(dr);
                }
                gcData.DataSource = dtFinal;
                gcData.DataBind();
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                throw;
            }

        }
```

Comment: You should wrap your connection and command objects in a USING statement so they will get disposed of. And why a try catch where the catch just throws the error again?

Comment: @SeanLange this is just for a demo code I dont know if this guy has used any class library or not

Comment: I get that but if they don't know any better this would wreck their connection pool. :)

Comment: that is true even also its not advisable to allow user to give alias name as that also cause sql injection

Comment: Not sure how the user specifying the column headers would allow sql injection.

Comment: @Kevin Shah..In your code we are giving same alias to all columns right? I need to customize it. Users must be able to give different alias to columns they want. Mean to say no two aliases of columns must be same

Comment: ok then aslo you can do this by passing each column name with alias that user has passed just need to do more specifc

Comment: How I can design it. Loading all column names to a dropdown, selecting a item and typing alias in textbox and button click. Can I have this in a better way